# Slicing list elements in Python 2.7.8

Tags: python, list, slice

I want to remove elements of list after element '//' in list including  this element

```
my_list = ['a', '=', 'x+y', '//', 'moo']

if '//' in my_list:
        my_list = my_list[0:my_list.index('//')]
print my_list
```

Wanted Output:

```
['a', '=', 'x+y']
```

Why this doesn't work ?

Comment: `mylist.index` is undefined, you want `my_list.index`

Comment: Of course it is my_list. Typo here, not in program.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you don't want regexes in the second case?

Comment: I have to solve problem without importing 're' and other libraries.

Comment: Please keep your posts to just **one** question at a time.

Comment: It seems strange that you want `'//'` in the output when `'/'` is one of the `list_operators`.  e.g. why don't you want:  `['a', '=', 'x','+','y','*','z', '/', '/', 'moo']`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer:

```
for index,line in enumerate(input):
    if '//' in line:
        input[index] = line[0:line.index('//')]
```

Answer (score 0):

The only reason it is not working is because you used "mylist" in the line shown below which you had not defined I guess it should be "my_list" there and will work so:

```
my_list = my_list[0:mylist.index('//')]
```

Comment: It's typo, I edited it.

Answer (score 0):

For slicing from i to j you need `[i:j+1]` :

```
>>> def split(my_list):
...  if '//' in my_list:
...      return my_list[0:my_list.index('//')+1]
...  else:
...      return my_list
... 
>>> split(my_list)
['a', '=', 'x+y', '//']
```

Comment: This doesn't produce the desired output, which does **not** include the `//`.

Comment: what about the edit ?